# Start Random Activities whenever the App is restarted

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-activity, grid-layout

Is there a way to get random activities displayed whenever the app is restarted? If not, what I want to get done is display grids of different sizes (ex: 3x3, 2x4, etc.) with buttons whenever the application restarts. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don’t know why you wouldn’t do this in a single activity but you can just start another activity by picking a random activity class from a list and finish the first activity immediately.

Comment: how to get it done in a single activity? @Tenfour04